# How to fill the part of the imageview with another color

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application in which I am using one `UIImageView` and adding one rectangle image to that `UIImageView`. I am getting some float value from another calculation like 67.4 and I need to place one green image on the 67.4 part of rectangle `UIImageView`. So please tell me how can I fill that green image onto that `UIImageView` ?

Comment: You should expand on what you mean by:  _"I am getting some float value from another calculation like 67.4"_  What property does that represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a "rectangle", i.e. a `UIView` and color it as you wish. Then add it to your image view.

```
UIView *greenRect = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:
   CGRectMake(67.4, 67.4, width, height)];
greenRect.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; 
[imageView addSubview:greenRect];
```

Comment: It's not a total solution.But somewhat useful.